# How can I create a touch event for a custom view

Tags: android, android-view, android-custom-view

Consider we have a custom view. When touched, we should go to another activity. How can I do this? Note, we should touch only the custom view. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use an `OnClickListener` like any other view?

Comment: Try with OnTouchListener http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
YourCustomView cv = (YourCustomView) findViewById(R.id.customviewid);
cv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        if (arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, YourNewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Just substitute `YourCustomView`, `YourCurrentActivity` and `YourNewActivity` accordingly.